# Pronunciation of "neural" in an American accent

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent

I am trying to pronounce the word *neural* in an American accent. I found it like *nooral*. Is that correct? Or should it be like *nywral*? or something else?

Comment: I say it **neral** where the first syllable rhymes with **her** or **fur**.

Comment: Slightly opinion based, isn't it? noo (boo) - rul (dull) is how I'd say it. (Clarification: I'd say it like "duhl" and not like "dole").

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, where are you from? I'm from Midwestern US, and I always hear "dole".

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I currently reside outside the US and that's where I grew up for most of my childhood. I never heard someone pronounce dull as dole but you learn something every day. This is how I've always heard it pronounced: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=2bCebIkpBw8. I thought you heard both versions? :) Anyway, we can also use skull for the sake of demonstrating my opinion.

Comment: In everyday speech I hear and say "dole".

Comment: Also, it's funny you used skull as an example, because that can also be "skuhl" or "skole". (I say skole)

Comment: Dictionaries supply pronunciation guides; most online dictionaries now include sound files with pronunciations. Please explain why you would need assistance beyond that, and what kind. Using letters to represent sounds is nearly useless unless a standard is referenced. Voting to close as off-topic, basic question.

Comment: To add to what @Jim said, there's also Forvo.com, a wedsite that let's you hear people from several locations speak a word. It's a good way to hear the many different ways a word may be pronounced, complete with local and regional accents. Unfortunately, it only has one listed for [neural](http://www.forvo.com/search/neural/en/), but you can also hear two for [neurons](http://www.forvo.com/word/neurons/#en), which is a similar word.

Answer (score 2):

This varies somewhat from place to place in the US.  To take another example, "new" is pronounced "nyoo" in some places and "noo" in others.  My mother was from the Boston area and she always said "nyoo", whereas the kids I grew up with in northern Indiana said "noo".  Whether you add the "y" sound is fairly consistent from word to word in a given place, meaning people that say "noo" will generally say "nooral".

At this point in time, it seems to me that Americans move around so much that it's often the case that different people pronounce it in different ways in the same place.

So, both are correct, the difference is regional, and the regional lines are blurring.

Comment: Yes, Marco, you'll be fine saying "nooral."  Note, radio and television journalists tend to say "nyooral."  (You could also say "nerral," as suggested by DJ, but that would make you a little harder to understand, which as an ELL you want to avoid.)

Comment: In most of the above answers, you could replace the A (or the U) in the suggested pronunciation with a _schwa_. but most of us can't make one on our keyboards. Nor any of the other fancy phonetic symbols.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock [This site's great. you can just put whatever you want in and then copy and paste it into your comments or posts!!](http://ipa.typeit.org/)

Comment: Thanks. That is cool. Unfortunately, I don't know how to use the other symbols properly—I suppose I'll have to learn.